# Is it possible to lock (enable/disable) cache memory?

Tags: debian, software-development

Please tell me if it is possible to lock cache memory of raspberry PI board. If so, what is the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not shure what cache you mean.

ARM L2 cache: 128kiB; probably not a good idea to disable it, the pi might become awfully slow. From http://elinux.org/RPiconfig : setting
`disable_l2cache` in config.txt disables ARM access to GPU's L2 cache. Default 0.
Needs corresponding L2 disabled kernel. 
This means: compile a custom kernel, replace your kernel.img etc with 
your custom build on the vfat partition of the SD card, and keep a copy of the files somewhere. Or grab & install berryboot (berryboot.com).

Linux kernel cache: from  http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2888/release-memory-used-by-the-linux-kernel-on-caches :

`free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free`

On 2nd thought, I assume you mean locking cache **out**, aren't you?

`echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

will swap as little as possible; default is 60. Note that I didn't try, I just removed the swapfile.

**Edit:** The linux kernel automagically assign unused memory pages to system cache, mostly for I/O. This can be write cache to mass storage, which is slow **and** can benefit a lot of reordering, to get contiguous sectors on a hdd, or to reduce erase block usage on flash based devices (sd card, ssd, usb key, etc). Search lwn.net for gory details about the kernel. (As a newbie here I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links in a post and I already cheated with 2 extra non-URL domain names :)
The cache pages are notably used for caching swap, the thing used to free real RAM, by putting the memory pages (the space allocated for a program) on the disk. This actually improve performance. Computing science is weird.
Cache is also used for network buffers.

`sync` force writes deferred to disks, to empty the pages used in **kernel space** as cache. They are now unused but remain allocated to the kernel. The proc thingy is a way to send an order to the kernel to mark these as free for use, in **user space** if need be.
Google `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` for more info.
`swappiness` controls the aggressiveness of the kernel about putting stuff that seems not to be used a lot to swap, **just in case** a user program might need some.
`free` is just there to show free memory before and after.

Again: *Linux Weekly News* is a good reference for understanding what is linux and how it works. Just try to understand what you can, and skip what makes you sick at a glance.

Hope this helps, at least for you to get a more precise question;)

Comment: I could not get the below lines.Could you please briefly explain this                                               free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
On 2nd thought, I assume you mean locking cache out, aren't you?

echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
will swap as little as possible; default is 60. Note that I didn't try, I just removed the swapfile.